# How to hide google re-captcha when login in react-native app?

Tags: react-native, expo

Recently I added login/register screen in my app but whenever I try to login then google re-captcha pop-up comes up. I want to hide this and login directly without verify google re-captcha.

Below is my code for this:

```
<FirebaseRecaptchaVerifierModal
  ref={recaptchaVerifier}
  firebaseConfig={firebaseConfig}
  attemptInvisibleVerification={attemptInvisibleVerification}
/>
```

Using expo firebase recaptcha module:

```
import { FirebaseRecaptchaVerifierModal } from 'expo-firebase-recaptcha';
```

Answer (score 0):

captcha verification by setting the attemptInvisibleVerification to true

```
const attemptInvisibleVerification = true
```

or put directly true in the attemptInvisibleVerification attribut

```
<FirebaseRecaptchaVerifierModal
  ref={recaptchaVerifier}
  firebaseConfig={firebaseConfig}
  attemptInvisibleVerification={true}
/>
```

Comment: It's not working. I'd tried it.

Comment: you're using expo ?

Comment: yes. using expo for Test..

Comment: it's working find for me